# Focus for a custom control

Tags: winapi

I am creating effectively a custom control. I went about this by simply generating a window class and creating a window with it with WS_CHILD style. Initially the control accepts keyboard input. The problem I am having is that once another control in the same window receives focus, my custom control does not receive keyboard input any more. How can I obtain keyboard input from my custom control again after focus changes?

Comment: Keyboard input goes to the control with focus. If another control gets the focus then it will get the keyboard input instead of your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the Window pass WS_TABSTOP also along with other Window Styles. This will enable your custom control to get focus when user presses TAB key.
Please check the MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The solution works but I also had to return DLGC_WANTCHARS from the WM_GETDLGCODE message.